# Charts not rendering properly in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I've got a project that uses routing, currently with only one page. I pass that page this controller:

```
var ctrls = angular.module('controllers', []);

ctrls.controller('overviewController', function($scope){

$scope.meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo",
                "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre",
                "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];
$scope.gastos = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
$scope.ganancias = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];


});
```

Then, I've got a lot of inputs (two for each month, so there are 24) that work similarly to this, some aiming to "gastos" and others to "ganancias":

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Input field" ng-model="gastos[0]">
    </div>
```

(ignore the type="email", it's just for a css-bootstrap rule).

These are my imports:

```
<script src="plugins/angular-min.js"></script>
        <script src="plugins/angular-route-min.js"></script>
        <script src="plugins/chart-min.js"></script>
        <script src="plugins/angular-chart.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <link href="css/angular-chart.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This should work, right? When I load the page, I see the inputs with the 0 values from the arrays. If I change values on the controller, they get shown on the inputs too, so the binding works properly.

Problem is, that these two charts never render, they only instantiate little white squares:

```
 <div class="col-6-md chart-area">
    <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut"
    chart-data="gastos" chart-labels="meses">
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut"
    chart-data="ganancias" chart-labels="meses">
    </canvas>
  </div>
```

Here you have an image to check how it actually looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzh02.png (there's still a lot of work to be done, that's why the page design sucks so much!).

I'd love to get some help with this, since I don't understand what's happening here...

edit:

In case you ask for the main module:

```
var main = angular.module("main", ['ngRoute', 'controllers', 'chart.js']);

main.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/overview', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/overview.html',
        controller: 'overviewController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/overview'
      });
}]);
```

Comment: hey, nice library I tried an example and it worked: https://jsfiddle.net/melaspela80/0ap9yqw8/

are you sure that your js includes are working?? check some error in the console window

Comment: Nothing appears on error window!

Answer (score 0):

It was just the input type="email" which was corrupting the number value. Now they render properly!

Comment: got it, when in angular you use a field like email and its value is not an email, that value is not passed to the scope, I had forget that part. the same occurs for input type number or date

Comment: That's what seems to happen. Once I changed it, it began working perfectly!